# Identify duplicates of one value with different values in another column

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have a dataframe of IDs and addresses. Normally, I would expect each recurring ID to have the same address in all observations, but some of my IDs have different addresses. I want to locate those observations that are duplicated on ID, but have at least 2 different addresses. Then, I want to randomize a new ID for one of them (an ID that didn't exist in the DF before).

For example:

```
ID     Address
1      X
1      X  
1      Y
2      Z
2      Z
3      A
3      B
4      C
4      D
4      E
5      F
5      F
5      F
```

Will return:

```
ID    Address
1      X
1      X  
6      Y
2      Z
2      Z
3      A
7      B
4      C
8      D
9      E
5      F
5      F
5      F
```

So what happened is the 3rd,7th, 9th and 10th observations got new IDs. I will mention that it is possible for an ID to have even more than 2 different addresses, so the granting of new IDs should happen for each unique address.

Edit:

I added a code for a longer example of a data frame, with rand column that should be ignored but kept in final output.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
             Address = c("x","x","y","z","z","a","b","c","d","e",
                         "f","f","f"),
             rand = sample(1:100, 13))
```

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: For creating the exampled data frame?

Comment: Based on the new dataset, what would be the expected output?

Comment: Added in the question the longer example and longer result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution with `tidyr` and functions `nest` / `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID,Address) %>% nest %>%
  `[<-`(duplicated(.$ID),"ID",max(.$ID, na.rm = TRUE) + 1:sum(duplicated(.$ID))) %>%
  unnest

# # A tibble: 13 x 3
# ID Address  rand
#    <dbl>  <fctr> <int>
#  1     1       x    58
#  2     1       x     4
#  3     6       y    75
#  4     2       z     5
#  5     2       z    19
#  6     3       a    55
#  7     7       b    34
#  8     4       c    53
#  9     8       d    98
# 10     9       e    97
# 11     5       f    13
# 12     5       f    64
# 13     5       f    80
```

If you use `magrittr`, replace `[<-` with `inset` if you want prettier code (same output).

Comment: This looks very compact, but I have some problems in replicating it.  Which version of tidyr you are using?

Comment: I updated the answer with data and package version, what error do you have ?

Comment: I have 0.7.1 version and I get `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(., duplicated(.$ID), "ID", max(.$ID) + 1:sum(duplicated(.$ID))) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ID'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ID'. 
3: In max(.$ID) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ID'.`

Comment: How would you expand this if I have additional columns that should be ignored, but kept in the final output? Added in the question a code for an example.

Comment: after updating the package I have the same error as @akrun

Comment: I get `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(., duplicated(.$ID), "ID", max(.$ID) + 1:sum(duplicated(.$ID))) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 13
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ID'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ID'. 
3: In max(.$ID) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'ID'. `

Comment: see updated solution, works with latest dplyr and with your updated example

Comment: I believe `nest` used to `group_by` all columns by default if table was not grouped, now it doesn't group at all and you get all your table grouped into one element only

Comment: This works great in the example, but for some reason in a larger data frame with many columns, I get NA's as IDs. I group by the ID and addres

Comment: Had an NA in one of my IDs. Added `na.rm= TRUE`  to `max` and it solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An option would be `data.table`.  After grouping by 'ID', `if` the number of `unique` 'Address' is greater than 1 and the 'Address' is not equal to the first `unique` 'Address', then get the row index (`.I`) and assign those 'ID' with the 'ID's that are not already in the original dataset

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[,  .I[if(uniqueN(Address)>1) Address != unique(Address)[1]], ID]$V1
df[i1, ID := head(setdiff(as.numeric(1:10), unique(df$ID)), length(i1))] 
df
#     ID Address rand
#  1:  1       x   58
#  2:  1       x    4
#  3:  6       y   75
#  4:  2       z    5
#  5:  2       z   19
#  6:  3       a   55
#  7:  7       b   34
#  8:  4       c   53
#  9:  8       d   98
# 10:  9       e   97
# 11:  5       f   13
# 12:  5       f   64
# 13:  5       f   80
```

---

Or we can use `base R`

```
ids <- names(which(rowSums(table(unique(df)))>1))
i2 <- with(df, ID %in% ids & Address != ave(as.character(Address), 
                     ID, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
df$ID[i2] <- head(setdiff(1:10, unique(df$ID)), sum(i2))
```