# Finding Maximumth value of currently mutating variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

While trying to work out this question [Identify duplicates of one value with different values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012120/identify-duplicates-of-one-value-with-different-values-in-another-column); I felt that the solution was closer but I couldn't because the `dplyr mutate` function refers to the pre-mutated state's `max` when I use `max(ID)` in the below code and not post-mutated value (like recursively).

The objective is to assign a new unique ID value for the rows where the current Address has mismatch with the previous Address of the same ID value.

The code I tried:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID     Address
1      X
                 1      X  
                 1      Y
                 2      Z
                 2      Z
                 3      A
                 3      B
                 4      C
                 4      D
                 4      E
                 5      F
                 5      F
                 5      F
                 ', header= T, stringsAsFactors = F)


df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(lag(Address)==Address,F,T))  %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(is.na(flag),F,flag)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(newID = ifelse(flag | is.na(flag), max(ID)+1,ID))%>% 
  select(ID = newID,Address)
```

Received Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 2
      ID Address
   <dbl>   <chr>
 1     1       X
 2     1       X
 3     6       Y
 4     2       Z
 5     2       Z
 6     3       A
 7     6       B
 8     4       C
 9     6       D
10     6       E
11     5       F
12     5       F
13     5       F
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    Address
1      X
1      X  
6      Y
2      Z
2      Z
3      A
7      B
4      C
8      D
9      E
5      F
5      F
5      F
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

Ideal code: Where I should've been able to use `newID` which is the current mutating variable to use.

```
> df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(lag(Address)==Address,F,T))  %>% 
+     mutate(flag = ifelse(is.na(flag),F,flag)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
+     mutate(newID = ifelse(flag | is.na(flag), max(newID)+1,ID))%>% 
+     select(ID = newID,Address)
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue, your expected output is what @akrun and I have given you in the linked post

Comment: I updated the code with how it should've been ideal. Does it help?

Comment: not really, I can't make sense of your post, but @akrun apparently could so you don't need me ;).

Comment: Sorry, but ironically, your ```tidyr``` solution is what motivated me to post this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is the `max(ID) + 1` which will give the constant value and the second problem is the `ifelse` itself which requires equal length vector for 'yes' and 'no'.  In the below solution, we replace the `max(ID) + 1` with `max(ID) + seq_len(sum(flag))` and instead of `ifelse` used `replace`

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(flag = lag(Address, default = Address[1])!= Address) %>%
   ungroup() %>% 
   mutate(newID = replace(ID, flag, max(ID) + seq_len(sum(flag))))%>% 
   select(ID = newID,Address)
# A tibble: 13 x 2
#      ID Address
#   <dbl>   <chr>
# 1     1       X
# 2     1       X
# 3     6       Y
# 4     2       Z
# 5     2       Z
# 6     3       A
# 7     7       B
# 8     4       C
# 9     8       D
#10     9       E
#11     5       F
#12     5       F
#13     5       F
```

In addition, the two `ifelse` statements to create the 'flag' can be replaced by a single statement

Comment: That's awesome! so is this part ```seq_len(sum(flag))``` using `TRUE` to create the incremental value?

Comment: @amrrs The `sum(flag)` is 4 and `seq_len(4)#[1] 1 2 3 4` so, it will give the increment you required

Comment: Without this knowledge i had literally hours banging my head. Thank you!

Comment: While we are here, Is there any way to use the current mutating variable inside the same mutate function? (Sorry if i'm confusing; that was kind of my question too)

Comment: @amrrs  You meant without creating the `flag`.  In that case, you have to do the creation of 'flag' at least 2 times and it wouldn't be that efficient

Comment: Yes, like in my mutate function newID is what I'm mutating; so is there any way to use same newID inside the function. like ```mutate(newID = ifelse(lag(newID)==newID,1,ID))``` something like this. sorry if it's unclear.

Comment: @amrrs Sorry, it is not clear to me.  After the `ungroup()`, you can directly update the 'ID' i.e. `transmute(ID = replace(ID, flag, max(ID) + seq_len(sum(flag))), Address)` and remove the `select`